# Create new reduce function in Dart to simplify call to fold

Tags: dart

In Dart, I have some helper functions for `Iterable` eg

```
extension Iterable2 on Iterable<int> {
  int get max => reduce(math.max);
  int get min => reduce(math.min);
  int get sum => reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  int reduce2<T>(int f(int element)) => fold(0, (a, b) => a + f(b));
}
```

The last one, `reduce2()`, is the one I'm adding so that I can write

```
aList.reduce2(afunc);
```

instead of

```
aList.fold(0, (a, b) => a + afunc(b));
```

I've made `reduce2()` take a function signed `f(int element)` because when I omitted `int` for the parameter (ie `f(element)`, I couldn't pass `afunc` to it since `reduce2()` was expecting `f` to have a `dynamic` parameter and `afunc()` expected an `int`.

I would like `reduce2()` to take a function that can accept any parameter (whatever the list contains) and not just an `int`.

For example, `reduce2()` should work for these:

```
int afunc1(int v) => v*v;
int afunc2(String s) => s.length;
int afunc3(MyClass obj) => obj.anIntProperty;
```

How can I change `reduce2()` to accept a function that itself can take any object and still do the totalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have currently defined the `reduce2` method in an extension on `Iterable<int>`, so you know that the elements are integers.

You will need a different extension, defined on arbitrary iterables instead:

```dart
extension GeneralIterableExtension<T> on Iterable<T> {
  int reduce2(int Function(T) convert) => this.fold(0, (a, b) => a + convert(b));
}
```

Comment: Many thanks - I didn't see the `<int>` in the original extension! There's a typo in your answer: the call to `reduce` should be changed to `fold`. I confused things by calling my method `reduce2` then calling `fold`. I'm going to call it `fold2` now.

Comment: BTW, different question but partly related: I did try to update my original extension to take `<num>` instead of `<int>` to make `sum` work on `int`s and `double`s. I changed the return type to `num` also but now it works on `double`s and not `int`s! Could you explain please?

Comment: Can't explain that without seeing it. If you change both occurrences of `int` to `num`, it should work and return a `num`. The biggest problem then would be that it returns an *integer* zero on the empty list, even if `convert` returns a `double`.

Comment: I've asked it as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65739652/creating-sum-min-max-properties-on-iterators-in-dart).