# Creating sum, min, max properties on iterators in Dart

Tags: dart, iterable

I have the following, which works for `int`s:

```
extension IterableInt on Iterable<int> {
  int get max => reduce(math.max);
  int get min => reduce(math.min);
  int get sum => reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

I wanted to make this more general to include decimals and created this:

```
extension IterableNum on Iterable<num> {
  num get max => reduce(math.max);
  num get min => reduce(math.min);
  num get sum => reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

These mostly fail, using the following tests:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5, 2.2].sum); //works
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5, 2.2].max); //works
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5, 2.2].min); //works
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5.0, 2.2].sum); //does not work

  print([1, 2, 3].max); //does not work
  print([1, 2, 3].min); //does not work
  print([1, 2, 3].sum); //does not work
}
```

The error returned for the `decimal` case is:

```
type '(num, num) => num' is not a subtype of type '(double, double) => double' of 'combine'
```

It's similar for `int`, referring to `int` instead of `double` in the message.

The pattern seems to be that if there is a mixture of `int`s and `decimal`s in the list then it's fine. If it's all `int`s or all `decimal`s, it fails.

I've redefined the properties (and added `multiply`) using `fold` and this works:

```
extension IterableNum on Iterable<num> {
  num get max => fold(first, math.max);
  num get min => fold(first, math.min);
  num get sum => fold(0, (a, b) => a + b);
  num get multiply => fold(1, (a, b) => a * b);
}
```

Can someone explain why the first version of `IterableNum` (using `reduce`) does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you create lists of higher levels (subclasses of `num` type).

Your (extension) code should be more generic (more universal).
Like this code: `extension IterableNum<T extends num> on Iterable<T>`.

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5, 2.2].runtimeType);
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5.0, 2.2].runtimeType);
}
```

Result:

```
List<num>
List<double>
```

Correct code as follow:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main(List<String> args) {
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5, 2.2].runtimeType);
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5.0, 2.2].runtimeType);

  print([1.2, 1.3, 5, 2.2].sum); //works
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5, 2.2].max); //works
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5, 2.2].min); //works
  print([1.2, 1.3, 5.0, 2.2].sum); // WORKS!!!

  print([1, 2, 3].max); // WORKS!!!
  print([1, 2, 3].min); // WORKS!!!
  print([1, 2, 3].sum); // WORKS!!!
}

extension IterableNum<T extends num> on Iterable<T> {
  T get max => reduce(math.max);
  T get min => reduce(math.min);
  T get sum => reduce((a, b) => a + b as T);
}
```

Result:

```
List<num>
List<double>
9.7
5
1.2
9.7
3
1
6
```

Comment: This works and I've learnt more about generics :) The `runTimeType` showed the issue nicely.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `reduce` is *very* picky about its parameter function.

A `List<int>`'s `reduce` requires a function of type `int Function(int, int)`. Nothing else will suffice. If you cast this `List<int>` to `List<num>`, you have something which seems like it expects to get a `num Function(num, num)`, but actually requires an `int Function(int, int)`. That's very hard to satisfy both of these (you need an `int Function(num, num)`, which `(a, b) => a + b` is not.
(This is all because Dart class generics is *unsafely* covariant. A `List<int>` is always considered a subtype of `List<num>`, even though some of the functions aren't actually usable at `List<num>`).

Use `fold` is a good solution. It allows you to specify a return type different from the element type. It also requires you to have a value of that type to begin with, which is why it isn't always possible to use `fold` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: Can you clarify that last sentence please? When _can't_ you use `fold` instead of `reduce`?

Comment: There might be situations where you need to "reduce" a list of special objects, ones where there is no neutral element to start with. Here you implement `max` as `fold(first, math.max)`, but that only works because seeing `first` twice doesn't matter. Say you had to find the sum of the lengths of a list of "words". There is no "empty word" to start out with, so you can't use `fold` because you have no first argument to it.

Comment: Thanks - understood. I've reverted to @mezoni's solution.